# Aem get page child ressources

Tags: java, aem, sling, jcr

I have a sling model, handling data related to an article_details_component ( basicaly titles, texts and images related to the article). In addition to these basic data, I need to create a list of object ( ArticleTeaser object ) that will be displayed in the recommendation section of my articles pages.

The logic is the following : I have a parent page called newsPage, under this page I create as many news articles as I want. within these pages I have the recommendations based on the other articles under my news page. the recommandation section is a List of teasers object, created based on the article_details_component title and image.

So I need to traverse my page jcr structure to get the article_componenet of the article page and retrieve its title and image in order to create my teasers.

Here is my code, but it is not working and I do not think it is the best way to do it :

```
private void getAllAvailableArticles(List<Page> childPages) {

List<Page> articlePages = childPages.stream()
    .filter(page -> !page.getPath().equals(currentPage.getPath())) //remove current article page 
    .filter(page -> {
      ValueMap props = page.getProperties();
      return Boolean.TRUE.equals(props.get("isTeasable", Boolean.class)); // check if the authore wants this article to be added to the recommendation section an other article
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

articlePages.forEach(page -> {
  Node n = resolver.getResource(page.getPath()).adaptTo(Node.class);
  Node jcrContent = null;
  NodeIterator childrenNodes = null;
  try {
    jcrContent = n.getNode("jcr:content");
    childrenNodes = jcrContent.getNodes();
    while (childrenNodes.hasNext()) {
      Node node = childrenNodes.nextNode();
      String resourceType = node.getProperty("sling:resourceType").getString();
      if (resourceType.equals("myproj/components/content/c06-news-internal/v1/c06-news-internal")) {
        teasers.add(ArticleTeaser.builder().teaserTitle(node.getProperty("teaserTitle").getString()).build());
      }
    }
  } catch (RepositoryException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
});
```

}

DO you have any Idea on how I can achieve this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, found a solution by getting my component node directly.

```
 @NotNull
 private void createRecommendations(List<Page> childPages) {

List<Page> articlePages = childPages.stream()
    .filter(page -> !page.getPath().equals(currentPage.getPath()))
    .filter(page -> {
      ValueMap props = page.getProperties();
      return Boolean.TRUE.equals(props.get("isTeasable", Boolean.class));
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

articlePages.forEach(page -> {
  Node n = resolver.getResource(page.getPath()).adaptTo(Node.class);
  Node newsInternalCmpnt = null;
  try {
    newsInternalCmpnt = n.getNode("jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/c06_news_internal");
    if (newsInternalCmpnt != null && newsInternalCmpnt.hasProperty("teaserTitle") && newsInternalCmpnt.hasNode("image")) {
      ArticleTeaser teaser = createTeaser(newsInternalCmpnt);
      this.teasers.add(teaser);
    }
  } catch (RepositoryException e) {
    LOGGER.error("unable to get news internal component node");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
});
```

}